# Does Vue allow template inheritance like Symfony does with Twig?

Tags: inheritance, vue.js, vue-component

I would like to be able to define blocks in Vue component's template, like this:

```
{# templates/blog/layout.html.twig #}
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Blog Application</h1>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

And then use the above template in a different component like:

```
{# templates/blog/index.html.twig #}
{% extends 'blog/layout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for entry in blog_entries %}
        <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ entry.body }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Examples come from: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/inheritance.html

Is this possible? I'm already using the extend API (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend) but overriding specific blocks isn't possible.

Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

Vue itself doesn't allow/support that, no.

However, if you're using Vue's [`Single File Components`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html), you can use a template engine which supports this, like pug or nunjucks, to write your templates.

To learn how to use pug with vue-loader, see [here](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#pug).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out!

Comment: @Linus-Borg does Vue 3 plans to support it natively? Also what is your opinion of this: https://github.com/mrodal/vue-inheritance-loader

Answer (score 0):

Use [Vue named slots](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#named-slots) for this.

```js
// BaseLayout.vue
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <slot name="header"></slot>
    </header>
    <main>
      <slot></slot>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <slot name="footer"></slot>
    </footer>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
// ChildComponent.vue
<template>
  <BaseLayout>
    <template #header>
      <h1>Here might be a page title</h1>
    </template>

    <template #default>
      <p>A paragraph for the main content.</p>
      <p>And another one.</p>
    </template>

    <template #footer>
      <p>Here's some contact info</p>
    </template>
  </BaseLayout>
</template>
```